# Unity Tilemap's WorldToCell always return with (0, 0, 0)?

Tags: unity, tilemap

Based on a **Vector2** I want to know the **coordinate** of the tilemap at that position.

But for some reason, it always returns **(0, 0, 0)**. Why?

Why?

```
var position = new Vector2(1.5, -0.5);
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    position += new Vector2(1, 3);
    var coordinates = tilemap.WorldToCell(position);
    Debug.Log(position + ", result: " + coordinates);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, that if the **Tilemap's object is disabled**, **WorldToCell will always return (0, 0, 0)**

Comment: It might have been good to include in your question the fact that you had disabled the tilemap object. Reproducing the problem in a new empty project can help you verify that you've included all relevant details in your description.

Comment: I didn't know that at that time it was disabled. And I was afraid of trying to reproduce it in an empty project, because there are too many factors that could cause the issue. I think trying to break a new empty project the same way as it currently malfunctions, is much harder then trying to figure out what broke the existing system.

Comment: You realize that if you don't do the work of reproducing your problem, then you're asking strangers to do that same work for you for free, without access to your original project for reference? This is tremendously counter-productive and leads to a lot of questions that never get a satisfying answer, because the key to the solution is hidden from everyone but the OP.

Comment: Yes, and I'm sorry. I always try to give the full picture, but I only reproduce the problem from the ground up if I can get all the necessary information. I posted this question because I thought that maybe I can get some hints or directions, thus making the progress faster. As soon as I discovered that at that point the tilemap is disabled, I tested it to find out whether that's what causing the issue. And yes, it was. If I would have known before, I would have shared.